# Ошибка легкого кода: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python

решил написать простенький кальулятор ,только ошибка в предпоследней строке:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'tuple'

```
# I = tok 
# U = naprezhenye 
# p = мощность 
# tok = moschonost / (1.73 *naprezhenye* cos f )
u = eval(input("введите напряжение: ") ) 
P = eval(input("введите мощность:")) 
z = 1.73 * u 
o = z * 0,86 
v = P/o 
print ("тoк:", v)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
o = z * 0,86
```

Замените запятую на точку.

Comment: спасибо, как всегда не замечаю мелочи